# Removing a element from list when obeying a certain condition

Tags: filtering, code-review, code-request, number-theory, number-representation

Well, I have the following code:

```
Select[PowersRepresentations[n, a, b], 
 DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]
```

This code finds `PowersRepresentations` a makes a list of the solution. Then `DuplicateFreeQ[#]` and `MemberQ[#, 0]` remove the ones that contain a duplicate or a $0$.

> Question: I want to add to the `Select` option that when a certain number shows up once in the entire list that element must be removed.

---

Example 1:

```
In[1]:=Select[PowersRepresentations[206, 3, 2], 
 DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]

Out[1]={{1, 3, 14}, {1, 6, 13}, {2, 9, 11}, {5, 9, 10}, {6, 7, 11}}
```

We can see that the numbers $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $10$, $13$ and $14$ turn up once. So the sets where they turn up must be removed from the list. So the code must give the following output:

```
{}
```

Example 2:

```
In[2]:=Select[PowersRepresentations[965, 3, 2], 
 DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]

Out[2]={{1, 8, 30}, {4, 7, 30}, {4, 18, 25}, {6, 20, 23}, {8, 15, 26}, {9, 
  10, 28}, {9, 20, 22}, {10, 17, 24}, {12, 14, 25}, {15, 16, 22}}
```

We can see that the numbers $1$, $6$, $7$, $12$, $16$, $17$, $18$, $23$, $24$, $26$ and $28$ turn up once. So the sets where they turn up must be removed from the list. So the code must give the following output:

```
{{9, 20, 22}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := Select[Min[Counts[Flatten @ x] /@ #] > 1 &] @ x
```

***Examples:***

```
f @ Select[DuplicateFreeQ[#] && FreeQ[#, 0] &] @ PowersRepresentations[206, 3, 2]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
f @ Select[DuplicateFreeQ[#] && FreeQ[#, 0] &] @ PowersRepresentations[965, 3, 2]
```

> {{9, 20, 22}}